# Unable to assign materials for .mtl in A-frame

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I have been trying to pull ids from.MTL file and assign materials using javascript via component. However, even though there are no errors am unable to assign the materials. Here's my method, would like to know where it's going wrong.

Is there any other method to pull in the ids and assign materials through javascript?

```
 <a-scene>
      <a-assets>

        <a-asset-item id="tree-obj" src="model/skin/house/house.obj"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="tree-mtl" src="model/skin/house/house.mtl"></a-asset-item>

      </a-assets>

      <a-camera position="0 1.6 0"> <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; maxDistance: 500; timeout: 200" position="0 0 -2" geometry="primitive:ring" material="color:black;shader:flat" scale=".03 .03 .03">

        </a-entity></a-camera>

        <a-entity example obj-model="obj: #tree-obj; mtl: #tree-mtl" position="0 0 0" rotation="0 0 0" scale="0.172 0.172 0.172"></a-entity>
        <a-image src="#shadow2" rotation="0 90 0" scale="0.015 0.015 0.015" ></a-image>
      </a-entity>


      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
      <a-light type="directional" color="#fff" intensity="0.7" position="-1 2 1"></a-light>
      <a-light type="ambient" color="#fff"></a-light>     
    </a-scene>
    <script>
  var Black;
AFRAME.registerComponent('example', {
    init: function() {
       var tex = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('sofa/chair.jpg');
Black = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  //name:"ID1",

  map:tex,
    color:0xffffff,
    combine: THREE.MixOperation,
    specular: 0xfafafa,            //bbaa99,
     shininess: 70,
     metalness:0.2,
     emissive:0x000000,
    reflectivity:0.7


})

    var el = this.el;  // Element to add click listener.



el.addEventListener('model-loaded', function (e) {
  e.detail.model.traverse(function(child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
    {
      if (child.material.name == "polySurface1_torso_MeshMat")  {
                                       child.material=Black;
                                        child.castShadow = true;
                                        child.receiveShadow = true;
                                    }

    }
  });
})    
    }
  })

    </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: Can you try setting a timeout/delay before setting the material and see what happens?

Comment: I tried with setting a delay and it worked. This should be one of the answer. Cheers. @ngokevin